# Не работает запись в файл PHP 7

Tags: php, linux, apache

Сервер на Linux, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.

Не работает следующий код (но на windows работал):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  file_put_contents("file.txt", ($_POST["username"] . ": " . $_POST["message"]), FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Comment: Если код не работает, он выдаёт ошибки

Comment: Ошибок нет, но запись не происходит...
И к тому же на windows работало.

Comment: а вы уверены, что каталог и/или файл доступны для записи?

Comment: Это /var/www/html, доступен всем пользователям для чтения и записи (как и файлы в нем)

Comment: @ArchDemon не надо заниматься гаданием на кофейной гуще. Если вы не обладаете базовыми навыками отладки, то не стоит пытаться отвечать на вопросы, связанные с неработающим кодом

Comment: @Nikita, если вы не видите ошибок, то это не значит, что их нет. Надо или смотреть в логах, или сделать так чтобы ошибки выводились на экран. После этого прочесть ошибку и исправить

Comment: @Ипатьев, маэстро, я, к сожалению, не постиг такого уровня высот, чтобы отлаживать код ментально. Ибо вопрос на SO не даёт доступа к удалённой машине вопрошающего. Из своей практике знаю, что самая частая ошибка с файлами при переходе с винды на иксы - права доступа. Но вы правы в том, что уровень программистов стремится к нулю, и уже всё больше народу не знает даже самых базовых вещей, такой как отладка кода.